Forced CCM Buck Operation
I bit confused regarding ripple voltage comparison for forced CCM mode buck converter and asynchronous buck converter in DCM. Which case we will have higher ripple voltage?
Next question, when should we use forced CCM mode configuration? I saw some design which are related to FPGA power supply where forced CCM mode used from entire load range, what benefits we gain from forced CCM while operating during entire load range?
In which conduction we will get higher efficiency for higher load case CCM or forced CCM?
Can anyone please clarify above doubts?

I don't understand your first question. All you seem to say is that you are confused about something.

Keeping CCM operation with a buck helps keeping the same dc transfer characteristics independently from operating conditions: $V_{out}=D.V_{in}$ in full- or light-load conditions. If DCM, this expression is no longer valid and load/switching frequency affect the characteristics. Same remark for the ac response which does almost not vary with a synchronous buck. You may have a slightly lower efficiency in this mode compared to DCM in light load though.

@Verbal Kint ...but for synchronous buck if we have forced CCM ,is that variable frequency or fixed frequency ? dont we get advantage in forced CCM having soft switching of the upper and bottom MOSFET?

No, fixed frequency is there and, yes, for a classical buck, you have hard switching conditions in light load.

Modern buck converters switch to DCM at low load currents for better efficiency.
The trade-off is higher ripple due to DCM.
With an extremely sensitive digital circuit like an FPGA being powered, that may switch between very low and very high consumption very rapidly, you want to be able to give it the best possible power you can under all conditions, so forced CCM is used to keep ripple low and to respond quickly to changes in the load current.
